# How to create a new instance of Azure Application Insights through the REST API

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-application-insights

I'd like to automate the setup of Azure Application Insights accounts for a ASP.Net web application.

I've installed the nuget package: `Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Insights -Pre` 
Now I'm looking at the [`Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.InsightsManagementClient`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/src/Insights/Generated/Management/Insights/InsightsManagementClient.cs)

There are lot's of operations to manage an existing account, except I can't find the one to create a new one.

**To be clear: On https://portal.azure.com I can click on `New > Create > Developer Services > Application Insights`. How do I do that in c#?**

Comment: I'm confused. Package you mention is Microsoft Azure Insights. In "To be clear" you mention Microsoft Application Insights. Which one you want?..

Comment: That seems to be part of my problem... The question then becomes: what nuget package can I use to manage "Application Insights"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Anastasia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4718626/anastasia-baranchenkova)'s [powershell example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30021650/how-to-create-a-new-instance-of-azure-application-insights-through-the-rest-api/30205261#30205261) I was able to look at the [powershell cmdlet implementation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell) and figure out, how to do this in code:

```
// initialize resource management client
var resourceManagement = new ResourceManagementClient(this.Credentials);
resourceManagement.Providers.RegisterAsync("microsoft.insights").Result;

// create identity & parameters for create call
var resourceIdentity = new ResourceIdentity(
    "SomeResourceName", // ResourceName
    "microsoft.insights/components", // ResourceType
    "2014-04-01" // Api Version
);
var parameters = new GenericResource {
    Location = 'centralus'
};

// send call off and hope for the best
var result = this.ManagementContext.ResourceManagement.Resources.CreateOrUpdateAsync(
    "SomeResourceGroupName",
    resourceIdentity,
    parameters,
    CancellationToken.None).Result;
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the script created by Eric Mattingly (You need Azure PowerShell installed for this to work):

```html
Output:
App Insights Name =  erimattestapp
IKey =  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

Script:  
cls

##################################################################
# Set Values
##################################################################

#If running manually, comment this out to before the first execution to login to the Azure Portal
#Add-AzureAccount

#Set the name of the Application Insights Resource
$appInsightsName = "erimatTestApp"

#Set the application name used for the value of the Tag "AppInsightsApp" - http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-preview-portal-using-tags/
$applicationTagName = "erimatTestApp"

#Set the name of the Resource Group to use.  By default will use the application Name as a starter
$resourceGroupName = "erimatTestAppRG"

##################################################################
# Create the Resource and Output the name and iKey
##################################################################
#Set the script to Resource Manager - http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powershell-azure-resource-manager/
Switch-AzureMode AzureResourceManager

#Select the azure subscription
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName "ECIT Preproduction Monitoring"

#Create the App Insights Resource
$resource = New-AzureResource -Name $appInsightsName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Tag @{ Name = "AppInsightsApp"; Value = $applicationTagName} -ResourceType "Microsoft.Insights/Components" -Location "Central US" -ApiVersion "2014-08-01"

#Give team owner access - http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-powershell/
New-AzureRoleAssignment -Mail "ECITTelemetryTeam@microsoft.com" -RoleDefinitionName Owner -Scope $resource.ResourceId | Out-Null

#Display iKey
Write-Host "App Insights Name = " $resource.Properties["Name"]
Write-Host "IKey = " $resource.Properties["InstrumentationKey"]
```